# How to change gravity axis/direction in Blender

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, blender, bulletphysics

I am making a videogame in Blender Game Engline, and want to be able to adjust the direction gravity pulls objects.  I can change [scene Z gravity](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_65_9/bge.types.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject) in a script, but that's one-dimensional along the Z axis.

I would be fine with the ability to set X, Y, and Z gravity, or an easy way to make everything rotate at the same time around the origin (or an arbitrary point).

I could also build a system if I could have a plane exert gravity or a force field and have it rotate around the center at a set distance (the entire gameworld is encased in a sphere).

Basically, I want to be able to, from a python script, cause a force on all dynamic objects, automatically and without . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [bge.constraints.setGravity(x, y, z)](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_65_10/bge.constraints.html?highlight=gravity#bge.constraints.setGravity)
To set the gravity.

and this one: [bge.logic.getCurrentScene().gravity](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_65_10/bge.types.KX_Scene.html?highlight=gravity#bge.types.KX_Scene.gravity) to get the actual gravity. According to this you should calculate the ideal rotation for your objects

Comment: You're awesome. This is exactly what I wanted, every thing I'd done before had been only ever doing Z axis. I did it with parenting to a central object which rotates and with a for-loop for anything not parented to that, but this is the better solution, so I'm going to switch to it.